# NHibernate using wrong table alias

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to filter a collection based on a foreign key.  I have two classes which are mapped with

```
public class GroupPriceOverrideMap:ClassMap<GroupPriceOverride>
    {
        public GroupPriceOverrideMap()
        {
            CompositeId()
                .KeyReference(x => x.Service,"ServiceCode")
                .KeyReference(x => x.CustomerAssetGroup, "GroupID");

            Map(x => x.Price);

            Table("accGroupPriceOverride");
        }
    }

public class CustomerAssetGroupMap:ClassMap<CustomerAssetGroup>
    {
        public CustomerAssetGroupMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.GroupID).Unique();

            Map(x => x.Description);

            References(x => x.Customer).Column("CustomerID");

            HasMany<GroupPriceOverride>(x => x.PriceOverrides).KeyColumn("GroupID");

            Table("accCustAssetGroup");
        }
    }
```

I query it using

```
_session.Linq<GroupPriceOverride>.Where(x => x.CustomerAssetGroup.GroupID == groupID)
```

However this is generating

```
SELECT this_.ServiceCode as ServiceC1_9_0_, this_.GroupID as GroupID9_0_, this_.Price as Price9_0_ FROM accGroupPriceOverride this_ WHERE customeras1_.GroupID = @p0
```

there where clause is referencing a table alias which doesn't exist(customeras1).  This is probably an alias for crossing with customerassetgroup but there is no need to perform that cross.  I'm sure that it is just something in my mapping with is wrong but I can't find it.  I've tried various column renaming in case the presence of GroupID in both tables was causing problems but that didn't fix it.  Any ideas?

**Edit**
I found that if I queried doing

```
_session.Linq<CustomerAssetGroup>().Where(x => x.GroupID == groupID).FirstOrDefault().PriceOverrides;
```

then I got the correct result.  I also found that if I saved a GroupPriceOverride and then queried for it using HQL then it wouldn't be found but I could still find the entity by loading the parent and looking at its collection of overrides.

```
_session.CreateQuery("FROM GroupPriceOverride i").List().Count;//returns 0
_session.CreateQuery("FROM CustomerAssetGroupi").List().FirstOrDefault().PriceOverrides.Count;//returns 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the old LINQ provider. Could you file a bug here:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

You might be able to get around it via:

```
_session.Linq<GroupPriceOverride>.Where(x => x.CustomerAssetGroup == group)
```

and let NHibernate figure out the ID. If you don't have the group already, you could do this:

```
var group = _session.Load<CustomerAssetGroup>(groupID);
_session.Linq<GroupPriceOverride>.Where(x => x.CustomerAssetGroup == group)
```

The ISession.Load(id) will only generate a proxy, but won't actually hit the database until you access a property (which you wouldn't be since you're just using it to specify the ID).

Comment: Thanks, James, I've created a unit test to demonstrate and opened issue http://216.121.112.228/browse/NHLQ-83

Comment: BTW - Are you using NH2.1.2 or NH3? If you're using NH3, try converting to use ISession.Query<T> (actually an extension method). Your bug is in the old LINQ provider, which has been deprecated. The new LINQ provider is a ground-up re-write.

Comment: 2.1.2, I'm sure there was a reason I wasn't using NH3 but it might have just been that nupack didn't have a fluent nhibernate for NH3(lazy).  I'll try rebuilding fluent against NH3 and using it instead.

Comment: I moved up to NH3 and my tests now pass perfectly.  The reason that I used NH2.1.2 in the first place was that I didn't realized that Linq was built into NH3 so I installed the NH.Linq package which pulled in NH2.1.2.  Lessons learned.

Comment: Be aware that the LINQ provider in NH3 is a ground-up re-write of LINQ-to-NHibernate. (L2NH was a proof of concept and very hacky.) So there are queries and constructs that work with Linq<T>, but not with Query<T> and vice versa. The NH team is planning to invest more heavily in Query<T> in the coming months. If you really run into a bind where Query<T> doesn't work, you can always use HQL, Criteria, QueryOver<T> (strongly-typed Criteria wrapper), ... You can even re-compile Linq<T> against NH3 and use that!